# Could we make a contraction of has if it is a main verb?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I real feel confused about ('s) followed by a noun it may be /is / or may be /has / such in this example : she's a baby .

Comment: It's not usual. If it were, that sentence would be ambiguous: 'She is a baby' vs 'She has a baby'. Contracting the 'is' is what's usually done.

Comment: I am not certain that your premise is correct "('s) followed by a noun it may be /is / or may be /has /" Typically, 's for has is only for has as an auxiliary verb, followed by a verb: "She's been up all night with the baby" = "She has been up all night with the baby

Comment: ***Only helping verbs contract***. is (to be) is a main verb in: She's a baby. versus She's had [has had] a baby recently.

Comment: @simon at rcl: You think it's "not unusual" to contract ***She has a baby*** to ***She's a baby***? I disagree. I suggest almost no native speakers would do this in any normal context, since there's a very high probability it would be understood as *She **IS** a baby*.

Comment: The contraction is often, idiomatically, an inefficient one. 'She's got a new baby' is how it is worded colloquially. In which case it would have been more concise to say 'She has a new baby'.We are creatures of mimicry and habit, not logic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - read again I said that it's *not* usual, and finished saying that contracting 'is' is what's usual.